# How to create multiple input fields on click

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have a drop-down where I have several option, what I want to do is which ever option is selected I want to create that much of input fields

**On change of select I am doing this**

```
    const Select_change = (e) => {
    let val = parseInt(e.target.value);
    console.log(val);
    switch (val) {
        case 2:
            setinputHolder((inputHolder) => [...inputHolder, 2]);

        case 3:
            setinputHolder((inputHolder) => [...inputHolder, 3]);

        case 4:
            setinputHolder((inputHolder) => [...inputHolder, 4]);
            console.log(inputHolder);
        default:
            setinputHolder((inputHolder) => [...inputHolder, val]);
    }
};

                    <select
                         onChange={Select_change}
                            name="Select_op"
                            className="form-control"
                            ref={register({ required: 'Please select IOT hub' })}>
                            <option value={1}>1</option>
                            <option value={2}>2</option>
                            <option value={3}>3</option>
                            <option value={4}>4</option>
                        </select>
```

I have created one state initial which is set to be 1 as I want to show one input field,after this what I am doing is

```
    const [inputHolder, setinputHolder] = useState([1]);
```

I am looping the input field on this basis

```
{inputHolder.map((li, index) => (
                    <div className="col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-8 col-lg-4 col-xl-4">
                        <div className="form-group input_form_label">
                            <input
                                type="text"
                                name="device_name"
                                id="device_name"
                                className="form-control"
                                placeholder="Device Name"
                                
                            />
                            <label className="common_label_form" htmlFor="device_name">
                                Device Name
                            </label>

                            
                        </div>
                    </div>
                ))}
```

But it is not working as expected, what If I have unknown nos in my drop-down let say 100, so I can not use switch to 100, I want a dynamic solution which will work fine.

[Here is my working code sandbox for better understanding](https://codesandbox.io/s/unruffled-lake-jcr71?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: So if you first click 2 and then 3 then there should be 5 input fields right?

Comment: Every time you change the dropdown, that concatenates a number into the inputHolder array. When you map the array, the number of times the dropdown changed + 1 will be the number of inputs rendered. Instead, use a single number in inputHolder instead of an array, and just change that number. Then use that number to generate an array of that length with `new Array(inputHolder)` and map that,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do below changes in your code

```
const Select_change = (e) => {
    let val = parseInt(e.target.value);
    setinputHolder(val);
  };
```

and while making input based on selected value

```
{[...Array(inputHolder).keys()].map(...)
```

so your logic will look like below code

```
<div className="row">
          {[...Array(inputHolder).keys()].map((li, index) => (
            <div className="col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-8 col-lg-4 col-xl-4">
              <div className="form-group input_form_label">
                <input
                  type="text"
                  name="device_name"
                  id="device_name"
                  className="form-control"
                  placeholder="Device Name"
                />
                <label className="common_label_form" htmlFor="device_name">
                  Device Name
                </label>
              </div>
            </div>
          ))}
        </div>
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/boring-dew-k1chw?file=/src/App.js